# Redirecting a page to 410 when a more global redirect is taking precedence

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-410

We've got a couple redirects in place sending everything inside member.php (member profiles) to the forum home page:

```
RewriteRule ^member.php/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/interact/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^member.php$ https://www.domain.com/interact/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Unfortunately we need a specific member profile to be 410 Gone due to some serious issues with Google rankings (long story - spammy backlinks to it):

https://www.domain.com/interact/member.php/82683-Donaldpab

The first set of redirects is causing the Donaldpab profile page to forward you to the forum home page instead of show it as 410.

We had this redirect in place for it, but its being ignored:

```
Redirect 410 /interact/member.php/82683-Donaldpab
```

Tried this one also:

```
RewriteRule ^interact/member.php/82683-Donaldpab$ - [G,L]
```

I'm not a developer/tech person so I'm randomly guessing.

Is there a way to retain the first set of redirects, and just make this one user profile go 410 Gone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following redirect solved the problem.  It allowed the overall "rules" for member profiles to remain in effect, while 410'ing the specific member profile:

```
RewriteRule ^member\.php/82683-Donaldpab$ - [G,NC]
```

Tested and confirmed with multiple profiles.